# Substituting SELECT return values in a postgres' query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got an issue to solve in a postgres model query.

The down below query returns me a table with three columns: "central", "imsi" and "mapver".
Sometimes, the query will return blank values in "mapver", but i can't let a blank space exist into it.
|
How can i make this query substitute the blanks by "-" or a word, like "WrongBlank"?
It is a varchar field.

```
SELECT Test_Configs.central, Test_Configs.imsi, 
       Test_Configs.mapver      

FROM config_imsis_centrais AS Default_Configs              -- Valores padrão da central correta
    LEFT JOIN config_imsis_centrais AS Test_Configs        -- Valores das centrais a serem testadas
        ON Default_Configs.central = 'ZBLM04'
        AND Default_Configs.ts = (SELECT MAX(ts) FROM config_imsis_centrais)
        AND Default_Configs.imsi = Test_Configs.imsi
        AND Default_Configs.ts = Test_Configs.ts
        AND Test_Configs.central <> Default_Configs.central
WHERE (                                                    -- Análise:
            COALESCE(Default_Configs.mapver, 'null') <> COALESCE(Test_Configs.mapver, 'null') AND
            Test_Configs.central <> ''
       )
```

A more simple example...
I often get:

```
central  |   imsi   |   mapver
--------------------------------
ZSPO03   |   74402  |   
ZSPO03   |   74401  |   
ZSPO03   |   72434  |   
ZSPO03   |   72415  |
```

But I want:

```
central  |   imsi   |   mapver
--------------------------------
ZSPO03   |   74402  |     -
ZSPO03   |   74401  |     -
ZSPO03   |   72434  |     -
ZSPO03   |   72415  |     -
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: COALESCE(Test_Configs.mapvar, "WrongBlank").

Comment: Sorry, should have been single quotes.  More info in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL

The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null. It is often used to substitute a default value for null values when data is retrieved for display, for example:

```
SELECT COALESCE(description, short_description, '(none)')
```

A text constant can never be null. So, if the things before it are null, the text string will be returned.

```
SELECT Test_Configs.central, Test_Configs.imsi, 
       COALESCE(Test_Configs.mapver, 'whatever string you want')      

FROM config_imsis_centrais AS Default_Configs              -- Valores padrão da central correta
    LEFT JOIN config_imsis_centrais AS Test_Configs        -- Valores das centrais a serem testadas
        ON Default_Configs.central = 'ZBLM04'
        AND Default_Configs.ts = (SELECT MAX(ts) FROM config_imsis_centrais)
        AND Default_Configs.imsi = Test_Configs.imsi
        AND Default_Configs.ts = Test_Configs.ts
        AND Test_Configs.central <> Default_Configs.central
WHERE (                                                    -- Análise:
            COALESCE(Default_Configs.mapver, 'null') <> COALESCE(Test_Configs.mapver, 'null') AND
            Test_Configs.central <> ''
       )
```

EDIT, has empty strings, not nulls

Reference: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE

```
SELECT Test_Configs.central, Test_Configs.imsi, 
       CASE Test_Configs.mapver WHEN '' THEN '-'
           ELSE COALESCE(Test_Configs.mapver, '-') 
       END AS mapver  

FROM config_imsis_centrais AS Default_Configs              -- Valores padrão da central correta
    LEFT JOIN config_imsis_centrais AS Test_Configs        -- Valores das centrais a serem testadas
        ON Default_Configs.central = 'ZBLM04'
        AND Default_Configs.ts = (SELECT MAX(ts) FROM config_imsis_centrais)
        AND Default_Configs.imsi = Test_Configs.imsi
        AND Default_Configs.ts = Test_Configs.ts
        AND Test_Configs.central <> Default_Configs.central
WHERE (                                                    -- Análise:
            COALESCE(Default_Configs.mapver, 'null') <> COALESCE(Test_Configs.mapver, 'null') AND
            Test_Configs.central <> ''
       )
```

Comment: Does the mapver column have empty strings instead of nulls?

Comment: They are feeded by a Perl Script daily, I found it almost now. I think they are empty strings...

Comment: Whoa, yes, I answered your question right before seeing it haha

Comment: It functioned! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Barbara, I'm creating a view with this COALESCE and when i get the column name in result of the query, I see it named as a "COALESCE", and not as a "mapver"... How could I make it being "mapver", no matter what?

Comment: You add AS mapver to the select.  I'll edit the answer above to show you.

Comment: Whoa, works like a charm. Thanks a lot, dear! This website is awesome! (:

Comment: I'm searching along how to learn this SQL thing, and I'm amazed, but it's hard on the beggining... Would you look for one of my other questions later, @Barbara? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670659/join-solution-on-postgres-with-many-tables see you!

Comment: You're very welcome.  I looked at your other question, and Clodoaldo Neto's answer is spot on.