# JOIN solution on Postgres with many tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Little issue on a Postgres database, being managed in Acqua Data Studio:

I need a solution to create a SELECT that concatenates many views into one table. There are more than 10 views.
One central may have many IDs, and one ID may have many centrals. So, the main table's PK would be the central-ID thing.

One example that applies (assuming that exist only 3 tables), as follows:

VIEW1:

```
 central   |   ID   |    MAP
--------------------------------
    A      |   01   |    MAP1      
    A      |   02   |    MAP1
    A      |   03   |     -
    B      |   01   |    MAP3
    B      |   02   |     -
    C      |   01   |     -
```

VIEW2:

```
 central   |   ID   |    CAMEL
--------------------------------
    A      |   01   |    CAP1
    B      |   01   |    CAP1
    B      |   02   |    CAP2
    B      |   03   |    CAP3
    D      |   01   |     -
```

VIEW3:

```
 central   |   ID   |    NRRG
--------------------------------
    A      |   01   |   NRRG2
    B      |   01   |     -
    C      |   01   |     -
    D      |   05   |   NRRG1
```

.
.
.

Resulting Table:

```
 central   |   ID   |    MAP    |  CAMEL  |  NRRG
--------------------------------------------------
    A      |   01   |    MAP1   |   CAP1  |  NRRG2
    A      |   02   |    MAP1   |         |  
    A      |   03   |     -     |         |
    B      |   01   |    MAP3   |   CAP1  |    -
    B      |   02   |     -     |   CAP2  |
    B      |   03   |           |   CAP3  |
    C      |   01   |     -     |         |    -
    D      |   01   |           |    -    |
    D      |   05   |           |         |  NRRG1
```

Any central-ID that appears in any of the 10+ tables need to enter in the concatenated table.
I surely don't care about blank spaces on those columns that don't have a correspondent into the other columns...
The important thing is to get, in each ID-central row every correspondent value that is present on the other tables. PS: "-" is a value!

I thought about a FULL OUTER JOIN, but whatching the references in manual I can't see a way to do it perfectly...

Thanks, fellas!

Comment: . . You should accept one of the answers, if you find that one works for you (I would go for the version using `using` because that is the more elegant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bb98d2/2)

```
select central, id, map, camel, nrrg
from
    v1
    full outer join
    v2 using (central, id)
    full outer join
    v3 using (central, id)
order by central, id
;
 central | id | map  | camel | nrrg  
---------+----+------+-------+-------
 A       |  1 | MAP1 | CAP1  | NRRG2
 A       |  2 | MAP1 |       | 
 A       |  3 |      |       | 
 B       |  1 | MAP3 | CAP1  | 
 B       |  2 |      | CAP2  | 
 B       |  3 |      | CAP3  | 
 C       |  1 |      |       | 
 D       |  1 |      |       | 
 D       |  5 |      |       | NRRG1
```

Comment: +1 . . . I didn't realize that the `using` clause would guarantee that the columns would be from the same row in the same table.  This is hard to express using `on`.

Comment: Will the "-" be returned too? I didn't try it yet, but in your result they don't appear

Comment: @a_horse I guess Gordon is talking about the select clause. But coalesce is our friend, just more typing work.

Comment: @a_horse I also guess that coalesce is what `using` does about the table ambiguity

Comment: @Zelda In my test data I replaced the dashes for null since you said it does not matter.

Comment: I guess it looks more simple with your first answer, Clodoaldo!

Comment: But the "-" are there to emule an - as it is, not a null. I asked it but when saw your fiddle, i noticed you just didn't add them to the tables, but it's fine, it functions with "-" too

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto . . . Add the row `('A',02,'NRRG3')` to the `v3` table in your SQL Fiddle.  Then you'll start to understand why the `full outer join` method with `on` is so cumbersome and why I'm so happy that `using` works in this case.

Comment: @Gordon Ok. Changed the "classic" join and it works now.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto . . . I could find another value that doesn't work.  Stick with the `using` or figure out how to make the classic join work in all cases (hint:  it is not pretty).

Comment: @Gordon Now I see what you mean. Try to break the new version.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto . . . And the problem with the new version is that `central` could match one preceding table and `id` another.  This is a good exercise for you.  But at least you can appreciate my wonder that `using` does the correct thing.

Comment: @Gordon I give up for now. Deleted the query.

Comment: I'll learn as much as you guys and help out people, in the forum. Thank you very much for making things a little MUCH easier to see, from my side

Answer (score 0):

A full outer join is extra complicated when you have composite keys.  Instead, use the `union all`/`group by` method:

```
select central, id, max(map) as map, max(camel) as camel, max(nrrg) as nrrg
from ((select central, id, map, null as camel, null as nrrg
       from view1
      ) union all
      (select central, id, null as map, camel, null as nrrg
       from view2
      ) union all
      (select central, id, null as map, null as camel, nrrg
       from view3
      )
     ) v
group by central, id;
```

Comment: I will try this out. It seemed really complicated with outer join! haha